# Swift black screen on only one view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image][image]

I have an issue on latest version of xcode.
Last day i change device and orientation in the **main.storyboard** and after one change of orientation only one view controller stay in landscape and when i change orientation in portrait this viewcontroller stay landscape and have black color.
Also try to delete the folder inside DerivedData but without any result.

Moreover main.storyboard show this error :

```
An internal error occurred, editing functionality may be limited
```

EDIT 1 : If i create another view controller it is created normally and show normally

EDIT 2 : This problem form only show when device is iphone 11

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you try to create a new `storyboard` if it can be done with lesser effort?

Comment: hi @S1LENTWARRIOR i added an image to my question and edit it, i also try to delete the folder inside derived data without any result

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues after update. Usually shutting down and relaunching Xcode helps.

Comment: shutting down mac or xcode ? i try to close all xcode and reopen it but the problem persist ... now i try to shut down mac

Comment: Xcode. I had a black storyboard and assistant not showing proper class from storyboard, or empty storyboard. After restarting Xcode it was fixed.

Comment: i try now to restart mac and xcode but problem persist

Comment: Have you tried to clean build? Menu >> Product >> Clean Build Folder

Comment: So the last hope AFAIK is to turn the computer off and on again. :/

Comment: I found that if change device the view show normal and problem fix

Comment: I have restarted my  MacBook pro and Xcode too, also try with device change but still the problem persist